# How do I access HttpContext.Current.Session in a class library?

Tags: session, c#-4.0, httpcontext, class-library, system.web

So, I am creating a class library that handles user information like username, password, etc.  I want to do this so that I can just reference this library with any of my web apps and not have to continuously rewrite the user information part.

In, the user information class library, I want to handle the login.  I've done this before in app_code that was a part of the web project by using `HttpContext.Current.Session`.  But, when I try to use it in my class library (even while `using System.Web`) it throws a compile error saying that HttpContext does not exist in this context.  How can I get access to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating a utility type class that works with a dependency like HttpContext, your best bet is to pass the context or the session into the class either via a constructor or the method call. That way, it is explicit to the consumers of your class that it requires this object to function.  This also allows you to test your class in isolation.

Even better, if you are working with a few specific properties that have basic types then you can accept those properties as inputs.  That way, you are not creating any dependencies on a UI framework for your utility library.

Comment: That is a good idea.  But, won't I still need to have access to HttpContext even as a parameter?  My big issue is that the code is not getting a reference to HttpContext.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't recognize the type when you declare the parameter?  Check to make sure you are not targeting Client Profile as the framework version.  It won't have System.Web.

Comment: Right, it does not recognize the type.  It is not targeting Client Profile and does have access to System.Web.  But, all System.Web has reference to is: System.Web..AspNetHostingPermission,       System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute, and                  System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.

Comment: You also need to add System.Web to your References.  It is confusing because those three classes are in the System.Web namespace with your standard references allowing you to add a using.  However, you don't get the full library until you specifically reference the DLL.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out while looking at my web app, I saw the reference to it.  Just in case anyone else needs to add it, the dll is located: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0